# Using NPM package in Meteor on the Client side

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm, package

I am having trouble using NPM packages in Meteor on the client side.  From what I have read this functionality is built into the Meteor framework.

Following the example given in on https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html using Moment package,
I am receiving this error 'SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module'

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. @Styx is right, we need to see your code. It sounds like you are doing an import inside a method or if statement, which isn't supported.

Comment: I have a template folder inside a js file at the top of the file i have 
import moment from 'moment';

Comment: where would be the proper place to put this statement